# Possible memory leak with malloc()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1000;

    //~600kb memory at this point
    auto m = (void**)malloc(x * sizeof(void*));
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        m[i] = malloc(x * sizeof(void*));

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        free(m[i]);

    free(m);

    //~1700kb memory at this point
    return 0;
}
```

When program starts memory consumption is about ~600kb, and when it ends ~1700kb. Is it memory leak or what?

Comment: "*Is it a memory leak or what?*" Have you run this through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) or some other debugging tool to detect memory leaks?

Comment: how do you measure the memory consumption?

Comment: @user463035818 through process manager when debugging

Comment: Since you're using C++ save yourself some headaches and at least use `auto m = std::vector<std::vector<type_wanted>>(num_rows, std::vector<type_wanted>(num_cols, default_value));`  Now you can't have a memory leak (unless you reall, *really*, try)

Comment: memory is not necessarily reclaimed by the OS immediately when you call `free`

Comment: free() does not necessarily return memory to the OS.

Comment: @NeilButterworth how is that? What is the purpose of calling free() then?

Comment: What happens if you wrap all of this in another loop that runs for a while? Does the memory skyrocket to no end or does it stop increasing at some point?

Comment: @patriot Do you want your program to slow down to a crawl?  The allocator is smart enough to *not* give the OS back the memory, in case you decide to reallocate again.  Second, the way you could determine a memory leak is to do what Blaze mentioned -- wrap that code in a function and call that function 10 times.  You will see the memory does not go through the roof, and the allocator is doing its job correctly.

Comment: @Blaze When you hit 2Gb (32 bit app without any large memory adaptations) it stops allocating memory - the return value from malloc is 0 (null).

Comment: I suspect the problem is your technique in measuring allocated memory consumption for `~600kb` and `~1700kb`.  I suspect you are not measuring what you think you are measuring.

Comment: @Rags what I mean is that if it is working properly, the memory shouldn't even go to 2GB and should reach an upper bound much sooner despite OP's observation that it's using 1.1KB more than in the beginning. In other words, if the loop is ran many times, it won't take an extra 1.1KB every time.

Comment: @Blaze Right - you are correct. As it stands, it doesn't leak, and goes nowhere near the 2Gb limit. You have to up the value of x quite a lot to do that. If you just run this code (with the malloc and free as they are) it doesn't leak. Behaviour is as expected, and the allocated pages are reused.

Comment: free() will normally hand back memory to the malloc/free allocation system, not the OS (it may be impossible to hand memory back to the OS) so that it can be re-used. Depending on your allocation/de-allocation  pattern this may result in your process's memory footprint increasing. This is not a memory leak.

Answer (score 7):

`malloc()` acquires memory from the system using a variety of platform-specific methods.  But `free()` does not necessarily always give memory back to the system.

One reason the behavior you're seeing might exist is that when you first call `malloc()` it will ask the system for a "chunk" of memory, say 1 MB as a hypothetical example.  Subsequent calls will be fulfilled from that same 1 MB chunk until it is exhausted, then another chunk will be allocated.

There is little reason to immediately return all allocated memory to the system just because the application is no longer using it.  Indeed, the most likely possibilities are that (a) the application requests more memory, in which case the recently freed pieces can be doled out again, or (b) the application terminates, in which case the system can efficiently clean up all its allocated memory in a single operation.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it memory leak or what?

No. You have each `malloc` matching a `free` and if I dont miss something you have no memory leak.

Note that what you see in the process manager is the memory assigned to the process. This is not necessarily equal to the memory actually in use by the process. The OS does not immediately reclaim it when you call `free`.

If you have a more complex code you can use a tool like valgrind to inspect it for leaks. Though, you better dont use manual memory managment at all, but use std containers instead (eg `std::vector` for dynamic arrays).

Answer (score 1):

`free()` and `malloc()` are part of your *Standard Library* and their behavior is **implementation dependent**. The standard does not require `free()` to release once acquired memory back to your Operating System.

How the memory is reserved is plattform specific. On POSIX systems the `mmap()` and `munmap()` system calls can be used.

Please Note that most Operating Systems implement **Paging**, allocating memory in chunks to processes anyway. So releasing each single byte would only pose a performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your application under management of operating system, the process of memory allocation in languages like C/C++ is two-fold. First, there is a business of actually requesting memory to be mapped into process from operating system. This is done through OS-specific call, and an application needs not bothering about it. On Linux this call is either `sbrk` or `mmap`, depending on several factors. However, this OS-requested memory is not directly accessible to C++ code, it has no control over it. Instead, C++ runtime manages it.
The second thing is actually providing a usable pointer to C/C++ code. This is also done by runtime when C++ code asks for it.

When C/C++ code calls `malloc`(or `new`), C++ runtime first determines, if it has enough continuous memory under it's management to provide a pointer to it to application code. This process is further complicated by efficiency optimizations inside `malloc`/`new`, which usually provide for several allocation arenas, used depending on object sizes, but we won't talk about it. If it has, the memory region will be marked as used by application, and a pointer will be returned to the code.

If there is no memory available, a chunk of memory would be requested from the OS. The size of the chunk normally will be way bigger than what was requested - because requesting from OS is expensive!

When the memory is `delete`d/`free`d, C++ runtime reclaims it. It might decide to return memory back to OS (for example, if there is a pressure in terms of total memory consumption on the machine), or it can just store it for future use. Many times memory will never be returned to the OS until process exits, so any OS-level tool will show process consuming memory, even though the code `delete`'d/`free`d it all!

It is also worth noting that usually application can request memory from OS bypassing C++ runtime. For example, on Linux it could be done through `mmap` call or, in bizarre cases, through `sbrk` - but in latter case you won't be able to use runtime memory management at all after this. If you use those mechanisms, you will immediately see process memory consumption growing or decreasing with every memory request or return.